# WPF Exception when binding type does not match

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, binding

What kind of an exception is WPF throwing, when the type which should be bound is not matching? For example if I bind the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to an `integer` property and than typing some letter (e.g.: *abc*) in the text field?

Comment: look at your output window

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in something called "Validation". There's a default validation, I believe, associated with binding integers to text etc that should automatically trigger.

By default it highlights the text box in a red rectangle and displays an error message. It also crucially doesn't update the source property.

You can add custom data validation messages (and for other criteria). To do this add `ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"` to your binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyInteger, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="100" Margin="20"/>
```

And make your data context inherit `IDataErrorInfo` and implement like follows:

```
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "MyInteger")
            {
                if (MyInteger < 0)
                {
                    return "Must be an integer greater than 0!";
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```